# Airdrop token code not working

Tags: solidity, remix, airdrop

I have this code to send a multi-transaction of token in a short airdrop

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract ERC20 {
function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _value) public returns (bool 
       success);
}

contract Airdrop {
function drop(ERC20 token, address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
  for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
    token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

I've deployed the contract but while it was successful, no token was received by the recipient. Do you see any errors here?

Comment: After deploying the contract, you must call the function `drop` with the parameters to have the tokes dropped. Did you do that? provide txn hash for people to check and get back to you

Comment: @Rajesh I call the function `drop`  this is the txn 0x993e9ad6fa4fb142c21ea1b6a010ff214ee09470c6dc8f80fe7c664cc8c47ff5
success but there are no Token send in the address I provide I set the token address with the token contract address and the recipient to the recipient and the amount to amount I want but success but not receive

Comment: Can you also explain how did you execute/call the function? Did you use Remix? Can you also provide how did you pass the parameters? If its remix, you enclose the recipients and values within square bracket, items separated by the comma, surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: I create a new contract for this do I  need to deploy this airdrop function in the same contract where I create the token? @Rajesh

Comment: Not required. It can be in a separate contract too. If you pass the parameters incorrectly you would get nothing. So, you will have to check the parameters passing again.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound stupid...
But did you send the tokens to the air drop contract?

The airdrop co tract will only be able to send the tokens that it (the contract address) holds.

Comment: yes I solve it now